# Notation regarding the mesh of Riemann integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I'm reading a book and one section is talking about the mesh regarding the Riemann integral. The section I am having trouble with is this:
" Now let the mesh of the partition go to zero, i.e:
$max(t_i - t_{i-1}) \rightarrow 0$
If we proceed in this way,  the points $t_i = t^{(n)}_i$ clearly have to depend on $n$ but we suppress this dependence in our notation. "

My question is; what is $t_i^{(n)}$? Specifically the ^(n).  This isn't raising $t_i$ to the power of $n$ so what is the $n$ representing?

Comment: We need the full context to answer with certainty. My bet is that a sequence of partitions $(\Pi^{(n)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is being considered in that paragraph and then $t_{i}^{(n)}$'s are the points in the $n$-th partition $\Pi^{(n)}$. Here, the superscript notation is nothing but a tag for the sequence index $n$ and not related to exponentiation.